# Javascript dont take changing from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take all the HTML from  a div container, to put it in a value in hidden field and then to show it to the users with the same CSS style but without textareas tags.

Instead of textareas, I want to show the value which came from the text fields (textarea)! So far so good!

But when a change the information in textareas my javascript code do not take the new information from that field.

What is wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['save'])){
            $scrita = $_POST['hid'];
            $scritaInsert = strip_tags($scrita, '<p><n><nz><font><bl><br><r><chh>');
            echo $scritaInsert;
            exit; //just for the test
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn-style" value="Save" id="submitContainer"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid"/>
        </form>
        <div id="container">
            <p style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 23px;color: black;">CocaCola</p>
            <p style="text-align: center; color: black; font-size:16px; text-decoration: underline;">
                The address
            </p>

            <p style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">
                To: <textarea name="do" style="width: 920px; max-width: 100%; height: 18px;">CocaCola Company</textarea>
            </p>

            <p style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">
                Attention: <textarea  name="vnimanieto" style="width: 830px; max-width: 100%; height: 18px;">CocaCola Company</textarea>
            </p>

            <p style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 19px;color: black;">
                CONTRACT<br>
            <n style="text-align: center;font-size: 16px;color: black;">
                For transport
            </n><br>
            <nz style="text-align: center;">№<textarea name="nomer" style="width: 60px; max-width: 100%; height: 18px;">1737</textarea>
                Date:<textarea name="date" style="width: 90px; max-width: 100%; height: 18px;" id="date">25.05.2016</textarea>
            </nz>
        </p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submitContainer').click(function(){
         $('.picker').html('');
        var content = $('#container').html();
        $('#hid').val(content);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the method `text()` not `html()`, because `html()` will just copy all the text including the HTML tag, but `text()` will only copy the real text.

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/rgtq3cta/).

Comment: When I change html to text in javascript code I loose my css style and when I put new value in the textarea the result is the same (the code take the existing value not the new one)

Comment: I help you update the code,hope this time i can soft your problem bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be the type of html slashes:

Try:

```
String.prototype.stripSlashes = function(){
    return this.replace(/\\(.)/mg, "$1");
}

$('#submitContainer').click(function(){
    $('.picker').html('');
    var content = $('#container').html();
    $('#hid').val(content.stripSlashes());
});
```

Comment: The result is the same. When I put new information in textareas the code do not take it and show the old information from textareas

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my JavaScript to the following code and it's now working properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submitContainer').click(function(){
        $('.picker').html('');
        $("textarea").each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).val());
        });
        var content = $('#container').html();
        $('#hid').val(content);
    });
</script>
```